How to integrate a class library in Azure Web App?
I have applications hosted as in Azure app service in a resource group. Similarly, I have various applications hosted in different subscriptions/RGs.
The below code/class library is developed using .Net
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;


namespace AKVClassLibrary
{
 public class KeyVaultService
 {
    private readonly string _keyVaultUrl;
    private readonly SecretClient _secretClient;

    public KeyVaultService(string keyVaultUrl)
    {
        _keyVaultUrl = keyVaultUrl;
        // Using DefaultAzureCredential allows the app to use managed identity for 
  authentication
        _secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(_keyVaultUrl), new 
 DefaultAzureCredential());
    }

    public async Task<string> GetSecretAsync(string secretName)
    {
        try
        {
            KeyVaultSecret secret = await _secretClient.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
            return secret.Value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error fetching secret: {ex.Message}");
            return null;
        }
      }
    }
 }

The code will fetch the secret from the Azure Key Vault. How to integrate the class library in the Azure Web Application? So that web application will get the secret from the from the Azure Key vault using the DLL?

Have you tried adding a reference to this DLL in your web application project? Once it is properly referenced, you should be able to use this class and its methods in your web application (assuming your web application is also a .Net application).

Is your issue resolved?

If I understand correctly, you want to build the Class Library - with fixed _keyVaultUrl and other applications can refer without specify or understand how _keyVaultUrl looks like. The generated DLL you may need to deploy it individually and does not remove any existing files in the destination directory, read more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#deploy-individual-files
You may also restart app service to get secret again
Actually, I would prefer expose the _keyVaultUrl and do handling add/retrieve secret in Configuration. There is completely secured because you can use Managed Identity - which allow authenticating Azure Key Vault from App Service, thus even with being leaked, user has no idea to authenticate and use _keyVaultUrl basically
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app?tabs=azure-cli
